# Submit html table data with via form (post)

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to post this html table on submit button click.

01 - I want to retrieve the data of this table in php code (server side)
02 - I also want to display this table on another page.

I'm using

PHP, JQuery

I have html table with many rows in form tag.

```
<form id="frm_test" class="form-vertical" method="post">
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text"  name="color_1" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text"  name="color_2" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text"  name="color_3" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text"  name="color_4" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    ......
    ......
    ......
    ......
    .....
  </table>

  <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

===========

there are 4 input fields in each row (4 cells in each row). and hundred rows in table. So if I get value via name in php code then I have to write lot of code to get 100(rows) * 4 (input fields) = 400 inputs. So my question was "What is the best way to achieve this"

Comment: You can use input type='hidden' to post data from table. For each value you want to send to server you have to have a input with a specific Name

Comment: what you have tried so far????

Answer (score 32):

Since you are trying to submit multiple rows of inputs/selects with the same 'name' attribute to a backend, you would need to add square brackets [] to the end of the name value in those inputs (in the table rows).

```
<form>
<input type="number" name="examplevar" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="color_1[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="color_2[]" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="color_1[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="color_2[]" /></td>
  </tr>
<table>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This tells your browser to create an array for that name property.

In php, read it as `$_POST['color_1'][0]` and `$_POST['color_2'][0]`, and loop as you'd like.

The brackets are in Phil Bailey's answer, but they are not pointed out.
(Added because a recent search led me to this)

Comment: "This tells your browser to create an array for that name property."

This is SUPER helpful information. :-)

Answer (score 4):

To post a form you need to add the `action` tag which termines the path to go when the form is submitted

```
<form id="frm_test" class="form-vertical" name="THE_PHP_FILE_TO_POST.php" method="post">
```

When you want to POST values you should specify `input` fields with a certain `name`. If you only want the table is visible you should use the `type` `hidden` so the form will POST data, but the inputs aren't visible.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        My value
        <input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="My value" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Once your form is posted you can catch the POST data in that PHP file like this:

```
//THE_PHP_FILE_TO_POST.php

if(isset($_POST))
{
    $myValue = $_POST['myValue']; //Contains the string "My value"
    //Do something with your POST
}
```

**EDIT** Get all table data

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    foreach($_POST as $inputName => $inputValue)
    {
        echo $inputName; //This is the name of an input field
        echo $inputValue; //This is the value of the input field 

    }
}
```

Comment: I have more then 400 inputs. it means I have to write 400 lines to getting table data. is there any good approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a an odd naming convention for for table input fields you need to specify the name for the file as an array. For the following SQL Statement using PDO one processing method.

```
select id,color_1,color_2,color_3,color_4 from colors;
<?php
// Get data
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
reset($results);
echo '<table>';
while (list(, $i = each($results)) {
  echo  '<tr><td><input type=hidden name="id[]" value="' . $i[0] . '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name="color_1[]" value="'  . $i[1] . '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name="color_2[]" value="'  . $i[2] . '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name="color_3[]" value="'  . $i[3] . '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name="color_4[]" value="'  . $i[4] . '"></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>
?>
```

Simplified $_POST print_r output for 4 records:

```
Array ( [[id] => Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 21 [2] => 44 [3] => 45 ) 
[color_1] => Array ( [0] =>red [1] =>green [2] =>yellow [3] =>blue ) 
[color_2] => Array ( [0] =>purple [1] =>orange [2] =>green [3] =>red ) 
[color_3] => Array ( [0] =>red [1] =>green [2] =>yellow [3] =>blue ) 
[color_4] => Array ( [0] =>purple [1] =>orange [2] =>green [3] =>red ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add input field in your table to post data.
like

```
<input type="text"  name="fieldname" value="" />
```

If you do not want to display field then you can make field hidden by using `type="hidden"`

Add action attribute in your form.

Action attribute indicates the url on which your data will be posted.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your reply. Yes there are 4 input fields in each row (4 cells in each row). and hundred rows in table. So if I get value via name in php code then I have to write lot of code to get 100(rows) * 4 (input fields) = 400 inputs. So my question was "What is the best way to achieve this"

Comment: it would be better if you can club the row data with some row-id/field-id so that a complete row is posted as array to reduce the name.