# Insert Table Data Into Database

Tags: php, mysqli

So I have a question like the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314062/submit-html-table-data-with-via-form-post) but since I can't comment I create a new thread instead it's just a clarification though. Is there no other way on how to insert a data from a table into the form without using the `<input type="hidden">` ?. As a novice, I felt it is too ugly to add an `<input type="hidden">` since someone might be able to snoop around by just inspecting the element in a browser.

Comment: You can store data in a session if you don't want it as a hidden element - though using a hidden input shouldn't pose much of an issue anyways.

Comment: As with any data the user passes to the web server, they can alter it.  Hidden/display only etc. data is still open to abuse.

Comment: thanks for the feedback i guess there's not much of a difference huh...